# error while building apache thrift

Tags: ubuntu, build, makefile, thrift, thrift-protocol

I tried to build (make) apache trift on my linux machine and I am faced with the following error during build process:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/developer/tools/apache-thrift/thrift-0.9.0/lib/erl'
./rebar get-deps
==> jsx (get-deps)
==> erl (get-deps)
./rebar compile
==> jsx (compile)
src/jsx_decoder.erl:123: redefining macro 'new_seq'
src/jsx_decoder.erl:126: redefining macro 'acc_seq'
src/jsx_decoder.erl:660: argument mismatch for macro 'acc_seq'
src/jsx_decoder.erl:626: function low_surrogate/4 undefined
src/jsx_decoder.erl:682: Warning: function is_partial_low/1 is unused
src/jsx_decoder.erl:692: Warning: function surrogate_to_codepoint/2 is unused
make[3]: *** [all] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/developer/tools/apache-thrift/thrift-0.9.0/lib/erl'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/developer/tools/apache-thrift/thrift-0.9.0/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/developer/tools/apache-thrift/thrift-0.9.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

could anybody help?
I am running `Ubuntu 10.04 LTS`  and made also sure i installed the [required libraries](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/ubuntu/)

Comment: once I had strange problems with ruby while compiling thrift 0.9 and 0.8 on my machine. Since I didn't need ruby in my thrift installation, I just turned it off: `./configure --with-ruby=no`. Do you need erlang support with thrift?

Comment: no i do not need erlang support. i switched it off with `./configure --with-erlang=no` and now it works :) thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just the same as my comment.

If you don't need erlang to work with thrift, simply turn it off while compiling thrift:

```
./configure --with-erlang=no
```

Probably you've got something messed up with erlang libs on your local machine and that's why you get the problem.